# JSON schema to allow date or empty string without using "oneOf" or "anyOf"

Tags: json, regex

I am looking for a Json pattern that allows date format only or empty string.

For some limitation in the software I cannot use "anyOf" or "oneOf" for now.

For example, the following fails for the code, although it is a valid Json syntax

```
"my_date": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        {
          "type": "string",
          "maxLength": 0
        }
      ] 
    }
```

also using this format below below is problematic as it will allow any string to go through for example "-"

```
"type": [
            "string",
            "null"
          ],
          "default": null
```

so I am thinking of using a **date pattern** as opposed to "date" format. Also this pattern should allow empty string

```
"pattern": "^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|)$"
```

So either we have

```
my_date = "2021-09-17"
```

or

```
my_date = ""
```

Any ideas will be appreciated

**Update**

This seems to work to have a date pattern or empty string

```
"my_date": { 
   "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|)$",
    "default": null, 
    "example": "2021-09-20" 
}
```

However it does not accept my_date = null.

How can I add my_date = null to this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

extend regex to accept null as well.

```
"my_date": { 
   "type": "string",
    "pattern": "^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|)$",
    "default": null, 
    "example": "2021-09-20" 
}
```

need to extend the pattern to include null

```
"pattern": "^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}||null)$",
```

**Explanation**

1. regex like POSIX uses ^ to denote the start of the line  and $ to indicate the end of the line
2. () are used to encapsulates the regex
3. The first pattern gives date in the format yyyy-MM-dd
4. | indicates an or-operator in regex
5. || indicates an empty string as the second validation
6. Add the third validation for null to the regex after the second or-operator

So the the pattern becomes

```
"pattern": "^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}||null)$"
```